# Constant HTTP Error 500 on Torrents

Tags: php, mysql, bittorrent

I am writing a program to add to announce.php for a torrent site.  Checks if catagory is a VIP catagory, then checks if torrent is seeding or leeching, then checks if user is a VIP.  When run, normal torrents stop (turn red) but other files work for non VIP member.  All the while Torrent Status in Utorrent shows "HTTP Error 500".  Does anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'passkey' =".sqlesc($passkey)) or err("Cannot Get User Details");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$memid = $row["id"];
$memclass = $row["class"];

//check if Torrent is a VIP Torrent
$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE info_hash=".sqlesc($info_hash)) or err("Cannot Get Torrent Details");; 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($row["category"]>=204 && $row["category"]<=218){ // Category 204 to 218 are all VIP Categories
goto tezt;//yes VIP
}
else{
goto enz;//no NON VIP
}
//is this Torrent Seeding only
tezt:
$query = ("SELECT 'seeder' FROM 'peers' WHERE ('userid' = $memid) AND 'torrent' = $torrentid") or err("Contact Admin");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
goto enz; // Torrent is seeding - even if user not VIP - okay to seed
}
// Torrent is downloading - do a VIP USER check
if ($memclass<=2){
      err("User can't download VIP Content");
}
enz:
```

Comment: Have you got access to the web server logs? You can find the line where the error occurs at there.

Comment: checked SQL Error and found nothing, other logs contain the same.

Comment: Found error finally - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'passkey' ='ed5ec22f9b05f105dc848b94e226f186'' at line 1. Query was: SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'passkey' ='ed5ec22f9b05f105dc848b94e226f186'."      I can find nothing wrong.

Comment: `users` shouldn't be within quotation marks. Change it to: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE passkey = 'ed5ec22f9b05f105dc848b94e226f186'`. `passkey` can be, but is not required.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted out a major problem